# How do I reevaluate all bindings in a multibinding when one of them changes?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a setup similar to this:

```
var binding1 = new Binding($"Item[0].IsChecked")
   {
        Source = sender,
        UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
        ConverterParameter = dependant
    };

    var binding2 = new Binding($"Item")
    {
        Source = sender,
        Converter = new AllItemsAreEqualConverter(),
        ConverterParameter = dependant
    };
    var multiBinding = new MultiBinding
    {
        Bindings = { binding1, binding2 }, Converter = unifyingConverter
    };
```

My model implements INotifyPropertyChanged and changing the IsChecked-property reevaluates binding1 as expected. However in practice by doing so the result of binding2 should also change. However I would also like to reevalute binding2 which is also part of my multibinding. Is it possible to tell the multibinding to reevaluate all sub-bindings when one of them has changed?

Just to add some more context which may or may not be helpful: I am trying to use this behavior in a telerik property grid that edit one or more objects that the same time, and my idea was that by having the first binding gives notification upon PropertyChanged for the IsChecked property, that would reevaluate the state of my binding, and the second binding would check the same property for all of the selected models making up the data set for the binding on the Visibility property of a specific property definition (the "unifyingConverter" refered to in my multibinding translates the values from the two sub bindings in to a Visibility).

Hope this is adequate information to answer my question. Thanks :)

Comment: "Is it possible to tell the multibinding to reevaluate all sub-bindings when one of them has changed?" - the answer is simple - no.

Comment: Whenever a Binding of a composed MultiBinding updates, all other bindings of this composition will be reevaluated. This means your MultiValueConverter will always receive the latest values returned by each Binding at once (passed to the converter as array).

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to tell the multibinding to reevaluate all sub-bindings when one of them has changed?

It "reevaluates" itself and the converter is invoked. In the `Convert` method you will then have access to the latest known values of all properties of all bindings that are part of the `MultiBinding`.

So when the `PropertyChanged` event is raised for the `IsChecked` property, the `Convert` method of the converter is invoked and in this method you can then get the latest value of both `IsChecked` (`values[0]`) and `Item` (`values[1]`).

For the converter to get invoked for the second property, you need to raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the `Item` property itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This was the behavior i assumed/experienced, however I can't raise PropertyChanged for the Item property as this is the user control which does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Make it a dependency property or implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` then.